# select2 multiselect filter options based on previous choices

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm implementing a select2 multiselect to choose between a number of competences. Competences have two slightly different scale of valuation.

Let say that “Programming”, “General problem solving” and “Speed” use Scale1; and “Intelligence”, “Change propension” and “Costs analysis”  use Scale2.
I would like that my select2 shows all 6 choices at first, but once I chose one of them, further selection are permitted only on competences that uses the same valuation scale.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Read the question 4 times. It is unclear to me. Can you give an example?

Comment: I have a multiselect. Let's say that it has a number of animals to choose from (cat, dog, squirrel, shark, blowfish, catfish). At first, every animal is avaiable, but if I choose dog, than only another mammal can be selected as second (or third) option. So, as per this example: cat (OK), cat + dog (OK), dog + shark (NO), catfish + shark + squirrel (NO). In other words I need to filter the multiselect options with a filter based on previous choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved.

My select2 are initialized on an existing select with options. So first of all I added a new attribute to the options, that represent the string I want to filter (in my case is 'scale', in the example I provided in the comments would be "animalGroup").

Then I set up a change event listener on the original select:

```
select.on('change', function () {
        var currItems = $(this).val();

        $(this).find('option').prop('disabled', false);

        if (!(currItems == null || currItems === false)) {

            var currScale = $(this).find("option[value='" + currItems[0] + "']").attr('scale');

            $(this).find('option').prop('disabled', false);
            $(this).find("option[scale='" + currItems[0] + "']").prop('disabled', false);;


            $(this).parent().find('option').each(function () {
                if (($(this).attr('scale') != currScale)) $(this).prop('disabled', true);
            });


        }

        $(this).select2({
            allowClear: true,
        });
    });
```

In enables all the option and then, if at least one option is selected, disables all the options that uses a different scale (or animalGroup). At the end the select2 is reinitialized to catch the changes in enabled/disabled.